# Show progressIndicator for each image added until that is uploaded in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web

I am looking for a way to show progressIndicator for each image added until that is uploaded in firebase like this example :

[image]

Use :

- Flutter Web
- [FilePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
- Firebase

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a Future `uploadImage()` using raw `statefulWidget` you can just say create a boolean and do something like this :

```
uploadImageButShowLoadingWhileProcessing() async {
   SetState((){
     bool isUploading = true;
   });
   await uploadImage();

   SetState((){
     bool isUploading = false;
   });
```

}
this will just set `isUploading` to true while it doesn't finish the uploadImage() method (while the image is not uploaded ).
when it completes then it will set it to false.

now in the `statefulWidget` you can set a ternary operator to the child widgets where you want to show it.
Example :

```
Container(
 child: isUploading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Image.network("HERE THE LINK GETTED FROM THE UPLOAD METHOD") 
   )
```

Comment: hi, thank you guy, i look to try it